# как увеличить размер собранного приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Собираю apk с помощью gradle приложение весит 500кб, нужно что бы весило 2 мб как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не совсем ответ на вопрос, а комментарии к комментариям ответа выше. Так как в комментарий все не входит, а оставить так как есть мне не позволяет совесть.

@ЮрийСПб - папка `/assets/` находится в корне проекта, а не в папке `/res/`/ Более того, разместив эту папку в `/res/` вы получите ошибку, так как ассеты не относятся к ресурсам приложения и не могут быть размещены в классе R.

Данный каталог используется для хранения данных, не относящихся к ресурсам самого приложения (таким как разметки, иконки и тп. содержимое каталога `/res/`) - например для хранения шрифтов, стартовой конфигурации БД, html-страниц и прочих произвольных файлов, нужных приложению, но не подходящих для размещения в `/res/`

Ассеты отличает возможность создать произвольную структуру каталогов внутри папки и отсутствие идентификаторов (не входит в класс R) для обращения к конкретному файлу. Для доступа к данным используется метод `getAssets()`

[Более подробно](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php) о назначении работе и юзкейсе ассетов.

@Andrew Папка `/assets/` и инструмент IDE *Image Asset* абсолютно разные вещи, которые не связаны ничем, кроме как совпадением слова. Первая используется для хранения произвольных данных, второе для подготовки изображений в каталог `/res/`.

Вы могли бы использовать и папку `/assets/` для решения своей задачи, только разместить ее надо было в корне проекта, на ОДНОМ уровне с папкой `/res/`, а не вложить в нее. Внутрь ассета вы могли помесить произвольный файл нужного размера, хоть вообще без расширения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб некоторые комментарии по комментариям.

Comment: Хм, как-то я проморгал этот ответ. Спасибо за пояснения)

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавьте картинку в папку `res/drawable`

Comment: Что такое assets ? Зачем нужны ?

Comment: `assets ` - папка в папке `res` где можно хранить файлы любого вида для последующего использования приложением.

Comment: не выходит так, пробовал добавлять, никакого эффекта

Comment: То, что папка это да) Я не совсем понимаю к чему ее применяют на практике?) Недавно в одном туториале увидел, что с помощью добавления assets(right click on res ⇒ New ⇒ Image Asset), можно легко добавить картину под все разрешения сразу, при этом на диске иметь один файл, а АС сама его порежит на размеры и положит в нужные папки(drawable-mdpi, -hdpi, etc..). Раньше я сам в ручную создавал папки под разрешения экранов и резал картинки сам и потом из соответственно раскидывал. В общем: с помощью добавления ассетов можно так "легко и быстро" добавлять картинки или это не корректно/неграмотно ?

Comment: Т.е. вы добавили файл весом в 1.5Мб и размер APK не увеличился?..

Comment: Как и зачем `assets` - я хз. Мне ни разу не понадобились за годы разработки под андроид.

Comment: да, добавил левый файл в папку, скомпилил апк, но размер остался прежним

Comment: Прекрасно) Спасибо, Вы ответили мне на вопрос, который меня беспокоил:)

Comment: @user193361, попробуйте тогда с картинкой в `res/drawable`

Comment: с картинкой вообще не компилит, вываливается ошибка в R.java

Comment: Картинка должна быть в формате `*.png`, имя файла картинки должно быть в нижнем регистре без пробелов. Например `test.png`

Comment: сработало с картинкой в формате png, спасибо